# Testing relationship between columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
     a      b     c     d    e
0 1.35   0.35  0.20  0.15  1.0
1 3.22   1.50  0.50  1.0  1.72  
...
```

Note that `a` is always equal to `b+d` and `b` is always equal to `c+d`.
I want to be able to point that relation in some way, in a way it looks like this:

```
      a      b        c     d    e
0     1.35   0.35  0.20  0.15  1.0
1     3.22   1.50  0.50  1.0  1.72  
level    1      2     3    3     2
```

Or

```
            a      b     c     d    e
0        1.35   0.35  0.20  0.15  1.0
1        3.22   1.50  0.50  1.0  1.72  
relation  b+e    c+d     -    -     -
```

Or some other way.
Can someone help?

**EDIT**
I don't want to find out how to add a row with those values, I want to detect the relations between the columns.

Comment: So you want to add a row to your dataframe? Or you want your dataframe to automatically calculate the relationship between the columns?

Comment: I want the dataframe to automatically calculate relationship between columns

Answer (score -1):

You can always add a level to your column names

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1.35,3.22],"b":[0.35,1.5],"c":[0.2,0.5],"d":[0.15,1],"e":[1,1.72]})

cols = [df.columns,
       ["b+e","c+d","-","-","-"]]
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*cols)))
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
    a     b    c     d     e
  b+e   c+d    -     -     -
 1.35  0.35  0.2  0.15  1.00
 3.22  1.50  0.5  1.00  1.72
```

Comment: Actually I want the code to detect the relations, not just add a row

Comment: well thanks for down voting my answer....  always best to spend time on defining requirement so solution becomes far easier to find